# Remove noexec from /tmp permanently

Tags: linux, mount, fstab

From a cloud provider I received a RHEL 7 VM which has `noexec` set on `/tmp`.

```
[user@myserver]mount | grep /tmp
tmpfs on /tmp type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,seclabel)
/dev/mapper/SystemVG-var_tmp on /var/tmp type xfs (rw,relatime,seclabel,attr2,inode64,noquota)
```

I am installing a tool that won't work properly with `noexec`. This is a COTS tool that I cannot change. To remove `noexec` I can do

```
mount -o remount,exec /tmp
```

The problem is that after reboot `/tmp` is `noexec` again.

in `/etc/fstab` I have the following lines pertaining

```
/dev/mapp/SystemCG-tmp /tmp xfs defaults 0 0
tmpfs /dev/shm tmpfs defaults,nodev,nosuid,noexec 0 0
```

When I remove `noexec` from the line above this also does not seem to have any effect. After reboot the `/tmp` folder is still `noexec`.

How can I permanently remove `noexec` from `/tmp`?

Comment: Have you viewed this page ? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/58684/remove-noexec-from-home-folder  Daisy has an answer from 2012, however, it is for Home but the /tmp is also there. [Allowing users to execute binaries from world-writable directories such as "/tmp" should never be necessary in normal operation and can expose the system to potential compromise. - https://stigviewer.com/stig/red_hat_enterprise_linux_6/2016-12-16/finding/V-57569 ]

Answer (score 1):

To modify the mount options for /tmp, regardless of whether this is a good idea, you should look into /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg. Since you mentioned the machine is "from a cloud-provider", its likely the default mounts are being set on boot by the cloud-init process.

Comment: +1. Even if the filename /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg isn't the solution, I think the general idea here is on track. Some cloud providers will make alterations on each reboot.  I've used chattr to positive effect to block such changes, but I heard that can also cause a machine to not boot in other configurations.  You might need to just let /tmp/ get the undesired mount option automatically, but then automatically remove that mount option (run the mount command you specify) after the cloud provider tinkers but before the [COTS](http://wikipedia.org/wiki/Commercial_off-the-shelf) software checks/cares.